# как правильно написать снижение объеМА добычи нефти или снижение объемОВ добычи нефти

Tags: грамматика

как правильно написать снижение объеМА добычи нефти или снижение объемОВ добычи нефти

Answer (score 2):

Смотря к какому количеству случаев добычи вы хотите это отнести: **объём** добычи нефти на такой то скважине за такой-то период (единичный случай) - напр. отмечено снижение годового **объёма** добычи, **объёмы** добычи там же при сопоставлении показателей за разные годы или месяцы могут различаться, **объемы** добычи нефти в разных странах увеличиваются или уменьшаются, а напр. за прошлый год произошло снижение суммарного **объёма** мировой добычи до такой-то цифры.

Comment: спасибо, большое за разъяснения